# Elasticsearch geo distance query prioritization for large radius

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial

I have a simple elasticsearch 7.4 index, containing multiple establishments with geolocation coordinates assigned to then. As a user in my geolocation app, I'll be requesting all 50 nearby establishments, based on my current location.

The problem with this approach is when the user zooms out of the map (very large radius) it will keep receiving only the nearest establishments in a tiny portion of the map.

I would like to retrieve other results scattered throughout the map by some kind of prioritization, like more well-known companies and partners that demand a higher priority. Google maps do a similar thing, but I'm not sure what kind of prioritization is done there.

What is the best way to achieve this using ES?

My current query is somewhat like this:

```
GET /places/_search
{
   "size": 50,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
               "distance": "10km",
               "coordinates": {
                  "lat": -2.000000,
                  "lon": -4.000000
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "sort": [
      {
         "_geo_distance": {
            "coordinates": {
               "lat": -2.000000,
               "lon": -4.000000
            },
            "order": "asc",
            "unit": "m",
            "distance_type": "arc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Seems you need to had an etablishment ranking ? Have you some example?

Comment: @LeBigCat Yes, some kind of establishment ranking. Considering a very large dataset, so when the user is requesting establishment in the 1~20km range i will ignore it, but when he widens the search for more than that (which would return the same data because it already reached the limit before without any optimization) I would start considering that ranking so the user could retrieve results outside the initial 1~20km range which may be more appealing considering the ranking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar case in the past, I had 2 fields geo_coordinates and priority of a product, and I had to sort the products using both of these fields by taking some configurable weight of each field
 With function score query u can redefine the elastic internal scoring formula, instead of just using text relevance sorting u can ask elastic to include the geo_distance also in the scoring mechanism, there are diff functions u can use for this case I used `linear` and `field_value_factor`
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

```
POST geotest/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
           "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "function_score": {
            "min_score": 0.1,
            "functions": [
              {
                "weight": 1,//weight of coordinates
                "linear": {
                  "coor": {
                    "offset": "500m",
                    "origin": [
                      106.82,
                      -6.22425
                    ],
                    "scale": "500m"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "field_value_factor": {
                  "factor": 1,//weight of priority
                  "field": "priority",
                  "modifier": "log2p"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

just take care of the factor in field_value_factor it's a logarithmic function so u need to adjust its value accordingly

[Edited]
To obtain same score for product at distance 100m and 10km, you have to define an area around the origin which can be done by `offset` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/images/decay_2d.png
all the products which lie inside `offset` radius will have same score and products which lie in `scale+offset` radius will have decreasing score
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

Comment: Let's say i don't have a weight or priority value just yet. I saw in the documentation that i could use a random_score, but i found it difficult to fine tune the results, have you ever used it? Another issue i had is how to sort the results after applying the function scores. If i add a sort by distance it affects the results i should be getting.

Comment: you don't need to do a sort, elastic automatically sort the documents based on the score u get by using function score

Comment: what do u mean by fine tuning, if u want to use random_score, your documents will be sorted by using radius and a random_score, that seems ok if u dont have priority yet and don't want only nearest result on top always

Comment: Yes, it does sort the results based on the score. It is ok for displaying markers in the map, but I would also display a list with all results to the user, that should be sorted by distance. If I can't do that in the query, I would need to do it afterward, probably in the BFF.

Comment: For the "fine-tuning" with the random_score, I mean balancing the results. Let's say we have 10.000 "products" in a 20km radius from a given location, but most of these points are very close to it (80% of them at a 1km radius). My query must return only 50 results, so when I'm searching with a large radius (say, 20km) I would like to retrieve a more "balanced" result. Let's say, 20% of "products" in that 0~1km distance and the other 80% in the other range (1.1km ~ 20km), using the random_score function. Was this clear enough?

Comment: why would u want to sort the list according to distance, since your origin isn't a fixed point, its an area

Comment: The "user" location (origin) is a fixed point. The results should be ordered by closest distance from it.

Comment: in that case, doing a sorting on application level sounds logical